# error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 54
    at Main.oddSort(Main.java:44)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

I understand that this error occurs because I am trying either trying to assign too many values in the array correct? I just don't know how to fix it or why what I did was wrong.

The assignment is to generate 100 random numbers, and to call two different functions, one after the other to assign the odd and even numbers into two different arrays and to display them.

Here is the section that is giving me trouble:

```
public static int[] oddSort ( int input[] )
{
    int amountOfOdd = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
            amountOfOdd++;
    }

    int[] odd = new int[amountOfOdd];

    for(int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
            /*it's this line specifically that doesn't work, according to the debugger*/
            odd[j] = input[i];
            j++;
    }
    return odd;
}
```

Here is the full thing:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[100];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++)
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 26);

        int[] odd = oddSort(numbers);
        int[] even= evenSort(numbers);

        System.out.println("The odd numbers are:");
        display( odd );
        System.out.println("The even number are:");
        display( even );
    }

    public static int[] oddSort ( int input[] )
    {
        int amountOfOdd = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
                amountOfOdd++;
        }

        int[] odd = new int[amountOfOdd];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
                odd[j] = input[i];
                j++;
        }
    return odd;
    }

    public static int[] evenSort ( int input[] )
    {
        int amountOfEven = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
                amountOfEven++;
        }

        int[] even = new int[amountOfEven];

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] % 2 != 0)
                even[j] = input[i];
                j++;
        }

    return even;
    }
    public static void display (int input[] )

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)

            System.out.print(input[i] + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: "this error occurs because I am trying to assign too many values in the array correct" - not exactly, it means "... an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array." See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the exception is the fact that you did not put the brackets around the body of your `if` condition. Should be like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
{
    if (input[i] % 2 != 0){        
        odd[j] = input[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Right now, what you are actually doing is increasing `j` every time through the loop, not every time there is an odd number. So of course you will get this exception when at least one value in the `input` is not odd since the `odd` array will have a size that is less than the size of `input`.

Comment: Good catch noticing that. This is why it's normally considered good practice to always use curly braces even if you are currently enclosing only one line of code, becasue as the code grows you'll end up making these kinds of mistakes.